# Why parameter screen_name of Twitter's API doesn't work? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I want to pull down the first tweet from a given username. From twitter's API，I guess I should use statuses/user_timeline and make screen_name a variable. But When I do this, I can only get my own tweet whatever screen_name is. Here is the code:

```
var Twitter = require("twitter");

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumer_secret:'yyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
  access_token_key: 'ooooooooooooooooo',
  access_token_secret: 'pppppppppppppppp' 
});

client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name:'Kobe Bryant',count:1},function(error, tweet, response) {
  if(error) console.log(error);
  console.log(tweet);  // Tweet body. 
  console.log(response);  // Raw response object. 
});
```

user_timeline page: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Like the code, I make screen_name 'Kobe Bryant', but it still returns my tweets.
The keys and secrets are generated by my account. Is this the reason that why I can only get my own tweets?
If I cannot get tweet from any given username with this API, then what can I do to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

"Kobe Bryant" is a user name. The screen name is `kobebryant`.

Comment: Yes it works. But how can I get the screen name from username? What to do with username like 'Kai-Fu Lee' ?